# Codeigniter - Create Unique Page View Counter

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a visitor counter for each my pages. According to PageId and visitor Ip, I created two tables such as pageView and pageTotalView. But my code is not working. I found some codes in php. How do I convert these codes to Codeigniter in working?

Database Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `pageView` (
 `pageViewId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pageViewPageId` int(11) NULL,
 `pageViewUserIP` text NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


// totalview

CREATE TABLE `pageTotalView` (
 `pageTotalViewId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pageTotalViewPId` int(11) NULL,
 `pageTotalVisit` text NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

PHP Codes:

```
// gets the user IP Address
  $pageViewUserIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  $check_ip = mysql_query("select pageViewUserIP from pageViewwhere pageViewPageId = 'I dont know How I can get viewing Page Id' and pageViewUserIP = '$pageViewUserIP'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($check_ip)>=1)
  {

  }
  else
  {
    $insertview = mysql_query("insert into pageView values('','I dont know How I can get viewing Page Id','$pageViewUserIP')");
    $updateview = mysql_query("update pageTotalView set pageTotalVisit = pageTotalVisit+1 where pageViewPageId ='I dont know How I can get viewing Page Id' ");
  }
```

To sum up, these codes maybe working on php, but How can I use these codes in Codeigniter?

Comment: Please refer this: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: How do you assign id to each page?

Comment: I created pages already. Each page has Id. When visitor visits page, system automatically add new insert to db if has unique IP address.

Comment: If your page has an ID, can't you get it from the page URL>?

Comment: yes. these codes not working on codeigniter. I need to these convert codeigniter.

Comment: I get only page Id. How can I get pageURL ?